# Passing FILE* as parameter

Tags: c, file, pointers

I know this is a common question but answers are varying a lot depending on context and not only have the found contexts been way simpler but also the found solutions haven't worked so far.

```
char* loadText(FILE** f, char* text){
    int nbytes, bufferSize = BUFFERSIZE;
    char* buff = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * bufferSize);
    while(1){
        nbytes = fread(buff, sizeof(char), bufferSize, *f);
        if(nbytes == bufferSize){
            bufferSize *= 2;
            buff = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * bufferSize);
        }
        else break;
    }
    text = buff;
    return text;
}

int main(){
    FILE* f = fopen("sometextfile.txt", "read");
    char* text;
    text = loadText(&f, text);
    fclose(f);
    printf("%s", text);
    return 0;
}
```

There is no output. I've also tried with loadText(File* f, char* text). Same results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you drop the data that has been read so far if it was too large to fit in your buffer, then keep reading where you left off. And if you don't read the entire buffer, it will always return a zero length string.

Comment: i don't have enough palms to cover my face with. thanks man

Answer (score -1):

```
char* loadText(FILE* f, char **text)
{
    size_t nbytes = 0, bufferSize = BUFFERSIZE;
    char* buff = malloc(bufferSize);
    if(!buff){/*error handling*/}
    while(1){
        nbytes += fread(buff + nbytes, 1, bufferSize - nbytes, f);
        if(nbytes == bufferSize)
        {
            char *tmp;
            bufferSize *= 2;
            tmp = realloc(buff, bufferSize);
            if(tmp) buff = tmp;
            else {/*error handling*/}
        }
        else break;
    }
    *text = buff;
    return *text;
}
```

Comment: the problem was solved by adding a rewind(f) call inside the nbytes==bufferSize condition. Thanks for the if(!buff) handleError tho, wasn't aware of that ^^